# how to find next max(id) in a table

Tags: mysql

lets say

My table contains

```
Id Status
1   0
2   1
3   0
4   0
5   1
6   0
```

I need output like

```
Id   Status
5      1
```

I tried like Max(id) but it gives output as

```
id   status
 6      0
```

Comment: What are the selection criteria?

Comment: So... you want MAX(status). no?

Comment: I don't need MAX(status) and all...

Comment: i need max(id) and status should not be 0

Answer (score 1):

I can only suppose, that you want to know about the maximum id of those entries having Status=1, right? Then use

```
select max(id) from mytable where Status=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, status
FROM myTable ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1 , 1
```

*I have assumed that you are looking for the second highest `Id` record values.*

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would like to have the max(id) where Status=1?

Then use `select max(id) from table where Status=1`

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to get the absolute max from both columns use :

```
SELECT GREATEST(MAX(id), MAX(status));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this also

```
    select Id,Status
    from table
    where Id=(
select MAX(Id) from table where Id <> (select MAX(Id) from table)


)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear what it is you actually want. From your example, I guess you want the maximum ID for the max status.

This is the max id for every status:

```
select max(id), status from table
group by status;
```

This will result in 5,1 and 6,0.

You could then filter out what you don't need, e.g.

```
select * from (
    select max(id), status from t
    group by status
) maxidperstatus
where maxidperstatus.status = (select max(status) from t);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want the Id where the status is the biggest 
Try this

```
select max(status),id from table group by id order by max(status) DESC
```